# LDAP get the groups which a user belongs

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, ldap

I'm newer coding ldap using spring-boot (ldapTemplate). I want to get the groups that a user belongs, get the list of membreOf attributes, I tried this:

```
@Override
    public Person getUserInfo(String uid, String orgnisationUnit) throws InvalidNameException {
        Name dn = bindDn(uid, orgnisationUnit);
        return (Person ) ldapTemplate.lookup(dn, new LdapMapper());
    }
```

This is myLdapMapper:

```
public class LdapMapper implements ContextMapper<Object> {

    @Override
    public Object mapFromContext(Object ctx) {
        DirContextAdapter context = (DirContextAdapter) ctx;
        Person p = new Person();
        p.setFirstName(context.getStringAttribute("cn"));
        p.setMailAddress(context.getStringAttribute("uid"));
          p.setRoles(context.getObjectAttributes("memberOf"));  // roles was declared like:  private Object[] roles

        return p;
    }

}
```

Would you have any propositions ?

Comment: Did you try this `context.getStringAttributes("roleNames")`

Comment: Propositions about what? What's the question?

Comment: About how I can get groups that a user belongs

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Spring Boot / Spring LDAP Get List of memberof for a User](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45546775/spring-boot-spring-ldap-get-list-of-memberof-for-a-user)

Answer (score -1):

```
import java.io.*;
import java.text.*;
import java.util.*;

import javax.naming.*;
import javax.naming.directory.*;
import javax.naming.ldap.InitialLdapContext;
import javax.xml.bind.*;

public class LdapConnection {

    public void getUserDetail(String user_name, String passwd) throws NamingException {
        DirContext ctx = null;
        String username = user_name;
        try {
            ctx = context(user_name, passwd);
            SearchControls searchCtls = new SearchControls();
            String returnedAtts[] = {"sn", "mail", "cn", "givenName",
                    "telephoneNumber", "manager","memberOf"};
            searchCtls.setReturningAttributes(returnedAtts);
            searchCtls.setSearchScope(SearchControls.SUBTREE_SCOPE);
            String searchFilter = "(&(objectClass=user)(mail=*))";
            String searchBase = "OU=India,DC=<Domain Component>";
            NamingEnumeration<?> answer = ctx.search(searchBase, searchFilter,
                    searchCtls);
            while (answer.hasMoreElements()) {
                SearchResult sr = (SearchResult) answer.next();
                Attributes attrs = sr.getAttributes();
                if (attrs != null) {
                    try {
                        String cn = attrs.get("cn").get().toString();
                        String mail_id = attrs.get("mail").get().toString();
                        NamingEnumeration<?> memberOf = attrs.get("memberOf").getAll();
                        while (answer.hasMoreElements()) {
                            String member =(String)memberOf.next();
                            System.out.println("memberOf : " + member);
                        }
                    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
                        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (NamingException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        } finally {
            if(!ctx.equals(null))
                ctx.close();       }
        }
    /**
     * This method will return Directory Context to the Called method,Used to
     * bind with LDAP
     */
    public DirContext context(String user, String passwd)
            throws NamingException {
        Hashtable<String, String> env = new Hashtable<String, String>();
        String adminName = "CN=" + user
                + ",OU=User,OU=India,DC=<Domain Component>";
        String adminPassword = passwd;
        String ldapURL = <ldapserver url with port>;
        env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY,
                "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");
        env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, ldapURL);
        env.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION, "simple");
        env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, adminName);
        env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, adminPassword);
        DirContext ctx = new InitialLdapContext(env, null);
        return ctx;    }
    public static void main(String[] args) throws NamingException {
        LdapConnection ldap = new LdapConnection();
        ldap.getUserDetail("username","password");
    }
}`
```

I hope this code will solve you problem.

Comment: Why are you catching '`NullPointerException`?

Comment: When you are trying to get an attribute which is not present for current user.Then you will get null pointer exception.

Comment: You should *test* for that, not handle it via a catch block. Poor coding.

Comment: Thanks for the comment.I will make sure in future i will do null check. instead of process it in catch block.