# Spring Boot / Spring LDAP Get List of memberof for a User

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-ldap

I want to get a list of a users attributes by querying on their ID from an LDAP repository structured like below

```
dn: uid=E000001 ,ou=People,o=Company,o=Internal
cn: BOB DOLE
statusid: active
memberof: cn=foo_group, cn=Foos, ou=Groups, o=Company,o=Internal
memberof: cn=bar_group, cn=Foos, ou=Groups, o=Company,o=Internal

dn: uid=E000002 ,ou=People,o=Company,o=Internal
cn: MARK TEST
statusid: active
memberof: cn=foo_group, cn=Foos, ou=Groups, o=Company,o=Internal
memberof: cn=bar_group, cn=Foos, ou=Groups, o=Company,o=Internal
```

So for example I query on the user id "E00001". I want to return this

```
["cn=foo_group, cn=Foos, ou=Groups, o=Company,o=Internal", "cn=bar_group, cn=Foos, ou=Groups, o=Company,o=Internal"
```

Answer (score 21):

Here's multiple ways to retrieve user groups:

- In case that you have a simple LDAP server with no nested groups, memberOf is usually enough:

  ```
  String userCN = "user1";

  //Get the attribute of user's "memberOf"
  ArrayList<?> membersOf = ldapTemplate.search(
          query().where("sAMAccountName").is(userCN),
          (AttributesMapper<ArrayList<?>>) attrs -> Collections.list(attrs.get("memberOf").getAll())
  ).get(0);
  ```
- But in case you have nested groups, things become more complicated:

  ```
  /*
   * Get user distinguised name, example: "user" -> "CN=User Name,OU=Groups,OU=Domain Users,DC=company,DC=something,DC=org"
   * This will be used for our query later
   */
  String distinguishedName = ldapTemplate.search(
          query().where("sAMAccountName").is(userCN),
          (AttributesMapper<String>) attrs -> attrs.get("distinguishedName").get().toString()
  ).get(0); //.get(0): we assume that search will return a result 

  /*
   * This one recursively search for all (nested) group that this user belongs to
   * "member:1.2.840.113556.1.4.1941:" is a magic attribute, Reference: 
   * https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa746475(v=vs.85).aspx
   * However, this filter is usually slow in case your ad directory is large.
   */
  List<String> allGroups = ldapTemplate.search(
          query().searchScope(SearchScope.SUBTREE)
                  .where("member:1.2.840.113556.1.4.1941:").is(distinguishedName),
          (AttributesMapper<String>) attrs -> attrs.get("cn").get().toString()
  );
  ```

**For googlers:** note that this has dependency of `org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-ldap`, and in case someone needs the Bean initialization code:

```
@Component
@EnableConfigurationProperties
public class Ldap {
    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix="ldap.contextSource")
    public LdapContextSource contextSource() {
        return new LdapContextSource();
    }

    @Bean
    public LdapTemplate ldapTemplate(ContextSource contextSource) {
        return new LdapTemplate(contextSource);
    }
}
```

with the following config template in application.yml:

```
ldap:
    contextSource:
        url: ldap://your-ldap.server
        base: dc=Company,dc=Domain,dc=Controller
        userDn: username
        password: hunter2
        #you'll want connection polling set to true so ldapTemplate reuse the connection when searching recursively
        pooled: true
```

---

**For when magic number's performance is bad:** The last one using magic number is actually quite slow if your ldap directory is large, and searching ldap recursively is faster in this case. Here's a helper class to exhaustively search all groups that a user belongs to:

```
public class LdapSearchRecursive {
    private final LdapTemplate ldapTemplate;
    private Set<String> groups;

    public LdapSearchRecursive(LdapTemplate ldapTemplate) {
        this.ldapTemplate = ldapTemplate;
        this.groups = new HashSet<>();
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve all groups that this user belongs to.
     */
    public Set<String> getAllGroupsForUserRecursively(String userCN) {
        List<String> distinguishedNames = this.ldapTemplate.search(
                query().where("objectCategory").is("user").and(
                        query().where("sAMAccountName").is(userCN)
                                .or(query().where("userPrincipalName").is(userCN))
                ),
                (AttributesMapper<String>) attrs -> attrs.get("distinguishedName").get().toString()
        );

        if (distinguishedNames.isEmpty()) {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("User not recognized in LDAP");
        }

        return this.getAllGroupsRecursivelyByUserDistinguishedName(distinguishedNames.get(0), null);
    }

    private Set<String> getAllGroupsRecursivelyByUserDistinguishedName(String dn, @Nullable String parentDN) {
        List<String> results = this.ldapTemplate.search(
                query().where("member").is(dn),
                (AttributesMapper<String>) attrs -> attrs.get("distinguishedName").get().toString()
        );

        for (String result : results) {
            if (!(result.equals(parentDN) //circular, ignore
                    || this.groups.contains(result) //duplicate, ignore
                    )) {
                this.getAllGroupsRecursivelyByUserDistinguishedName(result, dn);
            }
        }
        this.groups.addAll(results);

        return this.groups;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey ! Your solution(s) are working really good. But using the magic number in my system takes about ~5s whereas resolving it recursive manually like your 2nd answer suggested takes about ~50-60s. Do you have any explanation for this behaviour? :)

Comment: @jksevend It reallly depends on how your AD forest(s) is designed. Another possibiliy is: Did you set connection pooling as true? (pooled: true in your settings).

Comment: Do you mean ldap or spring settings with connection pooling? I really have no idea about the settings of the connections, just trying to map ldap roles to spring auhorities

Comment: @jksevend If you're not using spring settings, you can try calling `contextSource.setPooled(true);` , where `contextSource`  is your `LdapContextSource` (should be able to typecast `ContextSource` in your code).

Comment: Ahh alright, i tried it with the ```contextSource``` and it got down to ~8s. Seems like that using the magic number is a better approach for our system. Or maybe some additional internal ldap settings are required.