# LDAP Spring AD login only for users from specific group

Tags: spring, security, active-directory, ldap, spring-ldap

I'm struggling with login for users from specific group with use of LDAP/AD

For now unfortunately any user from company is able to login without knowing whether he belongs to a group  of not.

part of my SpringSecurity configuration:

```
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
auth
.ldapAuthentication()
.userDetailsContextMapper(new InetOrgPersonContextMapper())
.userSearchFilter("(sAMAccountName={0})")
.userSearchBase("OU=OU_USERS,dc=test1,dc=test2")
.groupSearchBase("OU=OU_Application,OU=OU_GROUPS,dc=test1,dc=test2")                
.groupSearchFilter("(&(objectCategory=Group)(memberOf=cn=G_Cpge,OU=OU_Application,OU=OU_GROUPS,dc=test1,dc=test2))")
.contextSource()
.url("ldap://XXXXXXXX")
.port(389)
.managerDn("CN=cpge,OU=OU_Services,OU=OU_USERS,dc=test1,dc=test2")
.managerPassword("password");
}
```

the problem is to set proper .groupSearchFilter to find given user in specified group in this case G_Cpge

`.groupSearchFilter("(&(objectCategory=Group)(memberOf=cn=G_Cpge,OU=OU_Application,OU=OU_GROUPS,dc=test1,dc=test2))")`

currently any user from any group can login:/ any ideas are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

I was also struggling with the almost same issue.
First of all - your user search filter should be like this so you don't need group search filter anymore

```
.userSearchFilter("(&(sAMAccountName={0})(memberOf=cn=G_Cpge,OU=OU_Application,OU=OU_GROUPS,dc=test1,dc=test2))")
```

However this solution didn't work for me. You need an interceptor to apply group criteria especially if you require to use an attribute instead of uid.

**DefaultLdapAuthoritiesPopulator** helps you to intercept authentication process and get groups of user.

Please check these two answers. To implement ldapAuthoritiesPopulator; https://stackoverflow.com/a/38319628/1926298

To get groups of specific user;
https://stackoverflow.com/a/49869085/1926298

Thanks